# Synchronize Dygraph swipe

Tags: javascript, synchronization, swipe, dygraphs

For my project I'm trying to synchronize two Dygraph graphs so they would both move when I swipe one (drag event with the mouse using the default Dygraph Library). Is there a Library or an easy way to implement this?

I found this example of Synchronizer online but it only supports selection and zoom (http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html) and I am not sure how to add swiping as well.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: What sort of phone are you using? Swiping any of the charts on that page on my iPhone changes the viewport on all the others as well.

Comment: As I realised later, the problem was on my side. So now it works like a charm and I managed to do what I needed for my project but thanks anyway. :)